# How to create edges between two lists of vertices in Sverchok

Tags: sverchok

I've got two sets of vertices in Sverchok:

[image]

I'm trying to draw edges between each corresponding vertex. I came up with this, but it seems overly complicated:

[image]

Are there any Sverchok nodes to simplify this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**List split**

You can use one node with the *List Split node*. You'll avoid the repetition of the double *Range Int* node.

[image]

It's just a slightly different variation from your implementation. Apart from building a node that makes all at once, I can't think of a way to simplify it further.

Answer (score 1):

try UV-connect node simply
join two objects by vertices into input sockets for uvconnect
http://nikitron.cc.ua/sverch/html/nodes/modifier_make/uv_connect.html
[image]

Comment: try many objects also, different parameters